# Get line of regex match in C

Tags: c, regex, numbers, line

I have written this code which finds files which finds the pattern "match" in the string *str* and prints it.

```
#include <regex.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    char *str = strdup("aaaaaaa match aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\n"
                       "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb\n"
                       "cc match ccccccccccccccccccccccccc");
    regex_t regex;
    regmatch_t match;
    regcomp(&regex, "match", REG_EXTENDED);
    while(regexec(&regex, str, 1, &match, 0) != REG_NOMATCH) {
        int beg = match.rm_so;
        int end = match.rm_eo;
        int len = end-beg;
        char *match_string = str+beg;
        match_string[len] = '\0';
        printf("%s\n", match_string);
        str = str + end + 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My problem is that I need to find on which line the match starts. Preferably this should work with multi-line matches, but single line is fine right now. Does regex have some hidden feature which I can use to solve this?

Comment: Normally you read line-by-line and process line-by-line so keeping track of which line is performed outside regex.

Comment: Why not use `strtok()` to split by new line or an another method to split the string?

Comment: That is a possible solution, now that I think about it I could keep a list of where each match begins and then afterwards iterate str to find the number of '\n' before the beginning of each match.

Comment: To make it compatible with multi-line matching.

Answer (score 2):

You can parse the lines with [`strtok()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtok.htm) to split the string at every `\n`.

Additionally, using a `struct` to store each line can be used:

```
typedef struct {
    char *str;
    size_t lineno;
} line_t;
```

Then once you know how many `\n` exist in the string, you can create an array of structs:

```
line_t *lines = malloc((numlines+1) * sizeof(line_t));
```

Each line will be stored like this:

```
Line 1: "aaaaaaa match aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
Line 2: "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb"
Line 3: "cc match ccccccccccccccccccccccccc";
```

Then you can simply use `strtok()` again to check patterns between the spaces. To compare strings, [`strcmp`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcmp.htm) will be good to use.

Here is some example code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    char *str;
    size_t lineno;
} line_t;

int main(void) {
    char str[] = "aaaaaaa match aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\n"
                 "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb\n"
                 "cc match ccccccccccccccccccccccccc";
    const char *key = "match";
    const char *delim1 = "\n";
    const char *delim2 = " ";
    char *pattern;
    size_t numlines = 0, count = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; str[i]; i++) {
        if (str[i] == '\n') {
            numlines++;
        }
    }

    line_t *lines = malloc((numlines+1) * sizeof(line_t));
    if (!lines) {
        printf("Cannot allocate %zu members\n", numlines+1);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    pattern = strtok(str, delim1);
    while (pattern != NULL) {
        lines[count].str = malloc(strlen(pattern)+1);
        if (!lines[count].str) {
            printf("Cannot allocate %zu bytes\n", strlen(pattern)+1);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        strcpy(lines[count].str, pattern);
        lines[count].lineno = count+1;
        count++;

        pattern = strtok(NULL, delim1);
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        pattern = strtok(lines[i].str, delim2);
        while (pattern != NULL) {
            if (strcmp(pattern, key) == 0) {
                printf("pattern '%s' found on line %zu\n", key, lines[i].lineno);
            }
            pattern = strtok(NULL, delim2);
        }
        free(lines[i].str);
        lines[i].str = NULL;
    }

    free(lines);
    lines = NULL;

    return 0;
}
```

**Note:** This code uses dynamic memory allocation with [`malloc()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_malloc.htm), and [`free()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_free.htm)'s the pointers at the end. If you would like me to explain these more, let me know.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this works well for most cases. I plan for my program to match '#include*<*>' patterns. I know of some cases where programmers stretch these out on multiple lines. Therefore I need to use multi-line matching, it might get tricky if I store the lines in an array. But I will definitely have use for this.

Comment: @Robert.S Yeah I think their are many ways to do this. I think its easier to use than regex though. Regex is sometimes tricky to use.

Answer (score 1):

In this code I save all matches to a linked list and then afterwards go through the string to find the line of the match. It seems to work well for the most part. If anyone knows of a better solution please let me know.

```
#include <regex.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct match_s match_t;

struct match_s {
    int beg;
    match_t *next;
};

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    char *str = strdup("aaaaaaa match aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\n"
                       "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb\n"
                       "cc match ccccccccccccccccccccccccc");
    match_t *head = NULL;      
    match_t *tail = NULL;      
    char *c = str;             
    regex_t regex;             
    regmatch_t match;          
    regcomp(&regex, "match", REG_EXTENDED);
    int prev = 0;
    while(regexec(&regex, str, 1, &match, 0) != REG_NOMATCH) {
        int beg = match.rm_so;
        int end = match.rm_eo;
        str = str + end + 1;
        match_t *match = malloc(sizeof(match_t));
        match->beg = beg + prev;
        match->next = NULL;
        prev += end+1;    
        if(head == NULL) {
            head = match;
            tail = match;
        } else {
            tail->next = match;
            tail = match;
        }
    }
    int line = 0;
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; c[i] != '\0' && head != NULL; i++) {
        if(c[i] == '\n') {
            line++;
        } else if(head->beg == i) {
            printf("Match on line: %d\n", line);
            match_t *tmp = head->next;
            free(head);
            head = tmp;
        }
    }
    free(str);
    return 0;
}
```